# Parity of integer with arbitrary bits in python

Tags: python, bit, parity

Lot of solutions suggest using xor with right shift, as described here
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/finding-the-parity-of-a-number-efficiently/

```
def findParity(x):
    x = x ^ (x >> 16); 
    x = x ^ (x >> 8); 
    x = x ^ (x >> 4);
    x = x ^ (x >> 2); 
    x = x ^ (x >> 1); 
    return x & 1;
```

But they assume 32 or 64 bit or some 2^n bits integer. In python integer could have any number of bits.  For instance i = 7, has only 3 bits.

```
i = 7
print(len(bin(i)) - 2)
```

Any suggestions on how to calculate parity using xor and right shift for arbitrary number of bits ?

Comment: Did you not try a loop testing bit 0 and shifting one bit right each iteration until the value is 0? Very easy to extend to doing eight bits at a time looking the lowest 8 bits up in a lookup table giving parity for that value.

Comment: Yeah that solution works, but it is not nlog(n) time solution. It  takes O(n) steps.
Look-up table is relatively complex solution.

Comment: What? Any other requirements not written into your question? Please share the best code you’ve written as a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a loop to dynamically change the length of the parity check:

```
def parity(num):
    length = math.ceil(math.log2(math.ceil(math.log2(num)+1)))
    for i in range(length-1, -1, -1):
        print(2**i)
        num^=(num >> (2**i))
    return num&1
```

You will need to use `log` twice because you first have to find the length of the number then you need `log` that many operations.

Comment: perfect, i was exploring in the same direction . I had overlooked the fact that log2 should be on the length of the bits, not on the value of integer.